# Can't visit https://gentoo.org when connected over NAT

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, nat

I have NAT configured on desktop for laptop to use. All is working except one thing: I cannot open https://gentoo.org. In `links` it hangs at "SSL negotiation. So, I guess this strange issue is related to SSL. All other HTTPS sites work fine.

NAT configuration on desktop:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

wg0: Internet interface of desktop
eth1: laptop is connected to this interface

`openssl s_client -connect www.gentoo.org:443 -prexit -debug` shows:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x557ba3f68e50 [0x557ba3f78d70] (316 bytes => 316 (0x13C))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 37 01 00 01-33 03 03 ca da b4 c8 0d   ....7...3.......
0010 - 7a 15 7b dc 4b cc 1b f9-1f 28 93 31 53 6b 6e 6f   z.{.K....(.1Skno
0020 - 56 1d c2 df 06 b2 eb 35-a9 e8 56 20 c4 85 26 09   V......5..V ..&.
0030 - 1c 4b 8f d2 52 cb 76 a5-2c 06 2a da d8 a0 83 e2   .K..R.v.,.*.....
0040 - 64 53 87 5e ba 63 d1 d8-0e 25 24 d1 00 3e 13 02   dS.^.c...%$..>..
0050 - 13 03 13 01 c0 2c c0 30-00 9f cc a9 cc a8 cc aa   .....,.0........
0060 - c0 2b c0 2f 00 9e c0 24-c0 28 00 6b c0 23 c0 27   .+./...$.(.k.#.'
0070 - 00 67 c0 0a c0 14 00 39-c0 09 c0 13 00 33 00 9d   .g.....9.....3..
0080 - 00 9c 00 3d 00 3c 00 35-00 2f 00 ff 01 00 00 ac   ...=.<.5./......
0090 - 00 00 00 13 00 11 00 00-0e 77 77 77 2e 67 65 6e   .........www.gen
00a0 - 74 6f 6f 2e 6f 72 67 00-0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00   too.org.........
00b0 - 0a 00 0c 00 0a 00 1d 00-17 00 1e 00 19 00 18 00   ................
00c0 - 23 00 00 00 16 00 00 00-17 00 00 00 0d 00 30 00   #.............0.
00d0 - 2e 04 03 05 03 06 03 08-07 08 08 08 09 08 0a 08   ................
00e0 - 0b 08 04 08 05 08 06 04-01 05 01 06 01 03 03 02   ................
00f0 - 03 03 01 02 01 03 02 02-02 04 02 05 02 06 02 00   ................
0100 - 2b 00 09 08 03 04 03 03-03 02 03 01 00 2d 00 02   +............-..
0110 - 01 01 00 33 00 26 00 24-00 1d 00 20 95 79 e4 57   ...3.&.$... .y.W
0120 - 04 d6 24 e3 cd 64 f7 16-89 f7 41 da dc 4d 12 45   ..$..d....A..M.E
0130 - 14 02 b5 b5 92 d0 f8 30-7a e0 cf 64               .......0z..d
```

and hangs.

Tried to debug using `openssl s_client -connect`

Comment: My guess is that this has nothing to do with NAT but instead with the wireguard VPN you are use for tunneling. This adds additional overhead to the data which might be in conflict with the assumed MTU of the link. See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/cy13jt/tls_handshake_errors_behind_wireguard_vpn/) for how to debug this also [here](https://keremerkan.net/posts/wireguard-mtu-fixes/) for how to fix it by explicitly setting a lower MTU for the interface.

Comment: Thank you, wireguard sets MTU 1420 while my laptop is connected to desktop with ethernet which sets MTU to 1500. I solved the problem with only one line on my laptop: `ifconfig enp3s0 mtu 1420 up`